Scaling Traffic Control (tc) for Limiting Bandwidth of 100k WireGuard Peers
I have many WireGuard peers using my server (linux) as a VPN, and I want to limit each peer to 10 Mbps. Using tc with hfsc, adding more than 16 filter rules to wg0 wasn't functional. Switching to htb instead of hfsc, I encountered failures after adding around 500 rules.
Requirement:
I need a solution to handle around 100k IPs with minimal overhead. Any approach using tc or an alternative method is welcome.
Proposal for Discussion:
One idea I've considered is using nftables/iptables to mark packets for different bandwidth classes (e.g., 10Mbps, 100Mbps). Then, configure tc to allocate bandwidth based on these marks. The benefit would be reducing the number of tc rules, focusing only on distinct bandwidth classes.
For example:

Mark all packets from IPs requiring 10Mbps with the same mark.
Mark other sets of IPs with marks corresponding to their required bandwidth.

However, I ran into an issue where packets with the same mark started sharing the bandwidth limit instead of having individual limits per IP.
